# In what sense could $x=y^5$ not be a function?

Tags: functions

I encountered a test question that asked which of the following does *not* represent a function:

1. $y=x+5$
2. $x = y + 5$
3. $y=5^x$
4. $y=x^5$
5. $x=y^5$

According to the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5qDQ.png), (5) does not. I am reasonably sure that the question is strictly *wrong*. The equation $x = y^5$ is presumably taken to represent not $y \mapsto y^5$ (as, by symmetry, (4) would be wrong too) but $x \mapsto x^{\frac15}$, but that is in fact a function, being the inverse of the bijective function $x \mapsto x^5$ (another way to see it is that the relation is *defined* as $x$ could be any real number and that it is *well-defined* as it is strictly increasing).

I am, unfortunately, all too aware of the idiosyncratically worded questions where, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D7rT.png), "which of the following is the largest possible value" is written where "which is the largest possible among the following" is actually meant.

**Am I missing something? Is there a possible interpretation of the question that, if weird, at least might make (5) or any other option a plausible answer?**

Comment: I think what they mean is that $y$ is $f(x)$. You are strictly right though I'd say, because that's just a convention.

Comment: But in that case, why would 2 be correct? Since that would also require rewriting.

Comment: @ColmBhandal I agree with Hetebrij that, even with that convention, (5) cannot be _the_ answer.

Comment: Because it's linear, and so invertible. A linear function is one to one, but a polynomial of greater degree isn't (or at least that one isn't). That is, (2) can be rearranged to $y = x - 5$, which is fine. But how do you invert (5)?

Comment: May be $x,y$ are restricted to integers?

Comment: @ColmBhandal use $y = \textrm{sgn}(x) | x | ^\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: With that sort of questions I doubt it, but they might, just possibly, have heard of complex numbers, and that for every $x\neq 0$ there are five values of $y$ such that $x = y^5$. Or they may think that for $x < 0$ and non-integer $a$ the expression $x^a$ never makes sense.

Comment: Actually, none of them is a function at all, they are just equations. To define a function, domain and codomain must be specified.

Comment: @ajotatxe Right. But the wording is "represent a function", and with some tacit conventions, all of them can reasonably be said to represent a function. Of course tacit conventions are very very dangerous because nobody knows which are in force.

Comment: @ColmBandhal: Your comment made me say "But they are in the… — wait, in the reals, so maybe they mean complex numbers!" gammatester's suggestion, although inapplicable here, would also make it work.

Comment: Yes I guess this is just another ill-worded question!

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the test, there seems to be an implicit assumption of the domains and ranges of functions being in the reals and imaginary numbers are only dealt with as far as $i$ squared being $-1$; however, introducing complex roots does single out (5) as incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The question is wrong. All of them are of a special kind of **statements** called **equations**, not **functions**.

Comment: The precise wording that it uses is which of the following equations does not _represent_ a function, so it is technically correct (if only by relying on a vague concept).

Comment: Also, the question was seeking interpretations that would result in a choice being correct, not ones in which the question is wrong — which are unfortunately plentiful in standardized testing.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: The reason for my answer is that **mathematically** the question does not make any sense and cannot be given any reasonable **consistent** interpretation. What could it mean by "represent"? Are you going to say that we must interpret $x$ as the input and $y$ as the output? But in **real mathematics** $x,y$ are both simply variables. Don't forget that the graph of a function is not the function either. Since this site is about mathematics, not tests, I do think that one should get the **correct** mathematical answers rather than ones that agrees with test setters.